# How can I revert to an earlier version of Factions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

A lot of the people I play Minecraft with like Factions. Now, I don't mean the most recent update to Factions; it's horrible. We want the previous version. How can I revert our version back to an older, more enjoyable time?

Comment: Just as a word of wisdom, the reason this question is getting downvotes is because of how it's worded. Opinions on if you like or hate an update don't really matter here. Simply asking how to revert to older versions would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

The [BukkitDev](http://dev.bukkit.org) website has a built-in archive system of sorts for past versions of all plugins. If you ever want to access a plugin's archive of versions, navigate to the plugin's main page, and on the top bar, you will see a *Files* button. Click that, and you will be able to download any specific version of your choosing.

[image: 'Files' button on BukkitDev]

The official Factions page can be located [here](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/factions/files/).